# values a re not being displayed in TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, textbox

in this program, when the Recall button (`recallBtn_Click()`) is clicked, it calls a method (that calculates directions) from another class which should then call the `showPath()` method. the show path method should then display its output in a textBox. But the values don't show even though i can see from debugging that the values are being sent to the text box. can anybody tell me where i went wrong?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        storeRetSelect.SelectedIndex = 0;
        PrioritySelect.SelectedIndex = 0;

    }

    public void showPath(List<PathFinderNode> mPath)
    {
        var T = new Form1().directionsTextBox;

        foreach (PathFinderNode node in mPath)
        {
            if ((node.X - node.PX) > 0) { T.Text += "Right" + System.Environment.NewLine ; }
            if ((node.X - node.PX) < 0) { T.Text += "Left" + System.Environment.NewLine; }
            if ((node.Y - node.PY) > 0) { T.Text += "UP" + System.Environment.NewLine; }
            if ((node.Y - node.PY) < 0) { T.Text += "Down" + System.Environment.NewLine; }
        }
    }

    private void recallBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var path = new pathPlan();
        string desigString = inputTextBox.Text;
        int[] desig = new int[3];

        for (int i = 0; i < desigString.Length; i++) { desig[i] = (int)char.GetNumericValue(desigString[i]); }
        path.Recall(desig[1], desig[2], (-1) * desig[0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With this line you are initialising a new object and get the reference of the textbox there.

```
var T = new Form1().directionsTextBox;
```

But I assume you want to use the textbox of the form which is allready open. Change the line to the following to access the textbox of the current object.

```
var T = this.directionsTextBox;
```

Comment: i tried it, didn't make a difference. But yes, the textbox is already in the form

Comment: @TobiAdediji if you set a breakpoint in the `showPath` method and look at the `this.inputTextBox.Text` value do you see the correct input? And furthermore does the `mPath` contain any values?

Comment: yes, mPath contains values, and i can see the right values in {this.inputTextBox.Text}

Comment: @TobiAdediji maybe check your code that you only initialize `Form1` once. Maybe there is somewhere else the same mistake as the on I mentioned in the question.

Comment: i've checked, i only initialize in the other classes

Comment: @TobiAdediji you should only have one instance of the class and pass the instance around instead of creating new ones.